# Android Development : How can I share the location of a marker I place on Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-maps-markers, send

My question is this:

How can I share the location of a marker I place on the map via touch position(Google Maps V2) I have an info window and can see the lat long. I tried and tried to set a button on the map to send the location of the placed marker, and I just can't get it to work.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Here is the code logic I have used:

```
public void setSendButton(Button sendButton) {
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.mymap);}


        public void onClick(View v, String Location) {

            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

            if (googleMap.getMyLocation() != null) {
                 googleMap.getMyLocation();
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Location = location.getLatitude() / 1E6 + "," + location.getLongitude() / 1E6;
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, settings.getString("message_subject", getString(R.string.share_location_subject)));
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, settings.getString("message_body", getString(R.string.share_location_body))
                    + " http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:"
                    + location);

            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.share_title)));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.no_way_to_share), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: "I just can't get it to work" -- that is not a useful description of your symptoms. Please explain what does not "work". For example, does your application crash? If so, where, and what is the stack trace?

Comment: It does not crash.I press the send button and nothing happens.

Comment: Where is your code that will respond to the button click? The `onClick()` method you have here will not be used directly, so presumably you are doing something else to respond to that click event.

Comment: I took the code from Context context = getApplicationContext(); statment down to the try statement and put that under on location change and got it to work without a button click. But that was close as I got and every time the gps would find lock it would run the intent over and over.... without getting the lat/long strings and putting them into the share message body.

Comment: Right now the above code is in the main activity,near the bottom and if I move it else where in the main activity, I have problems other than what I mentioned putting it under on location changed.

Comment: I have one main activity (MyMapActivity) and two XML files one for the map and one for the info window.

Comment: I have one main activity (MyMapActivity) and two XML files one for the map and one for the info window. –

Comment: Thank you for your insight and yes the onClick() method is not being  used directly, and is just sitting static.Please excuse the double entry nervous and wanting to get things right.

Comment: Observation and Answer was correct code was just static via misplaced logic. Turns out I did not need a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observation and Answer was correct code was just static via misplaced logic. Turns out I did not need a button.

Lesson is just use the objects methods.

Thanks to all.

Mike